# Using Script to add an ='Sheet1!'D3 formula that has a sheet name that is pulled within the script

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have this:

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var activesheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var RecipeList = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Recipe List')

var recipename = activesheet.getRange('D3').getValue();
var costperserve = activesheet.getRange('J5').getValue();
var foodcostpercentage = activesheet.getRange('J6').getValue();
var sellingprice = activesheet.getRange('J7').getValue();
var grossprofit = activesheet.getRange('J10').getValue();
var spreadsheetname = activesheet.getSheetName() ;
var Last = RecipeList.getLastRow();

RecipeList.getRange(Last+1,1,1,1).setValue(recipename), {contentsOnly:true};
RecipeList.getRange(Last+1,2,1,1).setValue(costperserve), {contentsOnly:true};  
RecipeList.getRange(Last+1,3,1,1).setValue(foodcostpercentage), 
{contentsOnly:true};  
RecipeList.getRange(Last+1,4,1,1).setValue(sellingprice), {contentsOnly:true};
RecipeList.getRange(Last+1,5,1,1).setValue(grossprofit), {contentsOnly:true};
RecipeList.getRange(Last+1,6,1,1).setValue(spreadsheetname), 
{contentsOnly:true};
```

Though  I want the values to  `= ( = 'spreadsheetname' !D3)` as a pose to just the value so I can change the value and it is updated.

Comment: If you want to set a formula, then set a formula. Right now you set a value. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) method that you can use exactly like `setValue()`, but it's not necessary. You can use [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) just as well here.

It looks like you're trying to pass an option of `{contentsOnly:true}` into `setValue()`, but that's not valid. As you can see in the linked documentation, this method doesn't allow any options. Moreover, it doesn't allow that particular option because it affects the contents only anyway.

Try this example code:

```
function insertFormulaTest() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Source Sheet");
  var sourceCell = sourceSheet.getRange("D3");
  var formula = "='" + sourceSheet.getName() + "'!" + sourceCell.getA1Notation(); // "='Source Sheet'!D3"
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Destination Sheet");
  destinationSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(formula);
}
```